# bind function to after() before() prepend()

Tags: jquery

I would like to do something like

```
$('body').bind('before after prepend', function(){ alert('somebody changed the html');});
```

anybody knows how to do this?

*(also I would like to do this without the use of any plugin)*

Comment: Why?  Tell and there might be some better way

Comment: We need more info: if your code example worked, what would it do?  Explain what results you expect, and we can help you figure out how to get there.

Comment: @ysth I apply jqueryUI classes (ui-state-default .. etc) to the html on document ready I also bind the styling func to .ajaxComplete (this is where all of my .after .prepend are and it works ), I wanted to know how to do it without binding to ajaxComplete, jquery.livequery does it somehow, but I don't want to use a plugin for this

Comment: @ysth here is a live link http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/lookupdemo , when a window pops up the html inside comes from the server and it is styled (.addClass) on .ajaxComplete which does .after .prepend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind on all events as [Live Query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) does.

Comment: I would like to do this without using a plugin

Comment: @Omu - Why not? what's you're rationale?...you'll end up writing the same code as the plugin....do you enjoy pain? :)

Comment: @Nick Craver I just thought that there could be an easier way for this single little purpose, also livequery is embedded in jquery, kinda

Comment: @Omu - nooooo, no it's not, `.live()` and `.livequery()` are *very* different things, `.live()` is an event handler, `.livequery()` *actively* searches for new elements.

Comment: I said *as* Live Query. So you could check the corresponding code and use is in your javascript code *without* the plugin